# Looping over a bidimensional array and extract data to a new one

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a *bidimensional array* like this:

```
const bArray = 
[ [ 'Hello World',
    'Hi everybody',
    'How are you?'
  ],
  [ { text: 'Hola Mundo',
      from: [Object],
      raw: '' },
    { text: 'Hola a todos',
      from: [Object],
      raw: '' },
    { text: 'Cómo estás?',
      from: [Object],
      raw: '' },
  ]
]
```

And I need to get as a result, only one array that should look like this:

```
[
 { en: 'Hello World',
   es: 'Hola Mundo' },

 { en: 'Hi everybody',
   es: 'Hola a todos' },

 { en: 'How are you?',
   es: 'Cómo estás?' },
]
```

This is how I do it:

```
let val1 = bArray[0].map(tuple => tuple);
let val2 = bArray[1].map(tuple => tuple);

let result = val1.reduce((arr, v, i) => arr.concat({"en" : v, "es" : val2[i].text}), []);
```

And now in the `result` variable, I have only one array with the result showed before.

---

**My question?**

Is there any improved way in which I can get the same result but with fewer lines of code? I mean, something like a combination of `map` with `reduce`, `filter` or `concat` without creating two separte arrays like `val1` and `val2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply do:

```
bArray[0].reduce((arr, v, i) => arr.concat({"en" : v, "es" : bArray[1][i].text}), []);
```

You can get the same thing in just one line.

**Explanation:**

```
let val1 = bArray[0].map(tuple => tuple);
let val2 = bArray[1].map(tuple => tuple);
```

This is doing nothing but get the elements in the array. It's exactly the same thing as:

```
let val1 = bArray[0];
let val2 = bArray[1];
```

So I just direct accessed the `bArray` indexes in your original line.

Comment: Amazing this one ! Exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sim meu amigo, você está certo :)

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming there will be only two arrays inside outer array. You simply need to loop on first array and pick the text from from other array at same index and merge them into one object.

```js
const bArray = 
[ [ 'Hello World',
    'Hi everybody',
    'How are you?'
  ],
  [ { text: 'Hola Mundo',
      from: [],
      raw: '' },
    { text: 'Hola a todos',
      from: [],
      raw: '' },
    { text: 'Cómo estás?',
      from: [],
      raw: '' },
  ]
];

let result = bArray[0].map((item, index) => {
   return {
     en: item,
     es: bArray[1][index].text
   };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Interesting answer ! Yes, only two arrays inside outer array.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another variation using `Array.prototype.forEach()` method

```
let result = [];
bArray[0].forEach((item, index) => {
   result.push({
     en: item,
       es: bArray[1][index].text
   });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Of course, `forEach` works too; and instead of `map`, you can't return here, so you need to *push* in an *array*. Easy to understand. Thanks for your answer.